# Defining a method without the function keyword or arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, function

I'm following a tutorial for the Amazon Alexa SDK at https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Developing-Your-First-Skill.html

It includes a code sample that defines an object with two methods.

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

I expected the methods to be defined in the form:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle: function(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  //etc...
}
```

Why does the code sample from the tutorial work?

Comment: It's an ES6 shorthand.

Comment: [It's a Method Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Your expected code would work too. The syntax in the example is relatively new.